# Displaying Last 10 rows for first page than next last 10 rows for next page

Tags: c#, .net

I am using this Function for displaying data in datagridview using paging ,using this on `page 1` I am getting Last 10 rows displayed properly ,but when I click on next button It should display `next last 10 rows` but it display top 10 rows on each next page ,I think their is mistake in my `cmd2 query of else part` but what is that ? I am using Access database

```
private DataTable GetCurrentRecords(int page, OleDbConnection con)
        {
            dt = new DataTable();

            if (page == 1)
            {
                cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("Select TOP " + PageSize + " QID,Question,Opt1,Opt2,Opt3,Opt4,AnsOp,Marks from Questions ORDER BY QID DESC", con);
                // CurrentPageIndex++;
            }
            else
            {
                int PreviouspageLimit = (page - 1) * PageSize;

                cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("Select TOP " + PageSize +
                    " QID,Question,Opt1,Opt2,Opt3,Opt4,AnsOp,Marks from Questions " +
                    "WHERE QID NOT IN " +
                "(Select TOP " + PreviouspageLimit + " QID from Questions ORDER BY QID DESC) ", con); // +
                //"order by MedicalClgID", con);
            }
            try
            {
                // con.Open();
                this.adp1.SelectCommand = cmd2;
                this.adp1.Fill(dt);
                txtPaging.Text = string.Format("{0} of {1} ", this.CurrentPageIndex, this.TotalPage);
            }
            finally
            {
                // con.Close();
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing `cmd2` to this give all rows in  DESCENDING ORDER

```
cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("Select TOP " + PageSize +
                    " QID,Question,Opt1,Opt2,Opt3,Opt4,AnsOp,Marks from Questions " +
                    "WHERE QID NOT IN " +
                "(Select TOP " + PreviouspageLimit + " QID from Questions ORDER BY QID DESC) " +
                "ORDER BY QID DESC", con);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can realize paging with over() at t-sql

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY task_id ) AS RowNum, QID,Question,Opt1,Opt2,Opt3,Opt4,AnsOp,Marks
          FROM      [Questions]         
        ) AS RowConstrainedResult
WHERE   RowNum >= 10
    AND RowNum < 20 
ORDER BY RowNum
```

Answer (score 0):

You have **2 options**:

### Option 1

*Create a new Stored Procedure* in your database as follows:

```
USE [YourDatabaseName]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE RelatedSchemaName.StoredProcedureName
    @bintStartingRowNumber bigint,
    @bintRowLength bigint
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    WITH AllRows AS
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY QID, DESC) AS RowNumber, *
        FROM Questions AS Q 
    ) 
    SELECT QID, Question, Opt1, Opt2, Opt3, Opt4, AnsOp, Marks
    FROM AllRows
    WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN @bintStartingRowNumber AND @bintStartingRowNumber + @bintRowLength
    ORDER BY QID, DESC
END
GO
```

Now, Add it in your project and then, change the following code lines:

```
if (page == 1)
{
    cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("Select TOP " + PageSize + " QID,Question,Opt1,Opt2,Opt3,Opt4,AnsOp,Marks from Questions ORDER BY QID DESC", con);
    // CurrentPageIndex++;
}
else
{
    int PreviouspageLimit = (page - 1) * PageSize;

    cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("Select TOP " + PageSize +
        " QID,Question,Opt1,Opt2,Opt3,Opt4,AnsOp,Marks from Questions " +
        "WHERE QID NOT IN " +
        "(Select TOP " + PreviouspageLimit + " QID from Questions ORDER BY QID DESC) ", con); // +
    //"order by MedicalClgID", con);
}
```

with this:

```
int intFirstRowNumber = (page - 1) * PageSize;

cmd2 = new SqlCommand(StoredProcedureName);
cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@bintStartingRowNumber", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = intFirstRowNumber;
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@bintRowLength", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = PageSize;
```

### Option 2

Change the following code lines:

```
if (page == 1)
{
    cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("Select TOP " + PageSize + " QID,Question,Opt1,Opt2,Opt3,Opt4,AnsOp,Marks from Questions ORDER BY QID DESC", con);
    // CurrentPageIndex++;
}
else
{
    int PreviouspageLimit = (page - 1) * PageSize;

    cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("Select TOP " + PageSize +
        " QID,Question,Opt1,Opt2,Opt3,Opt4,AnsOp,Marks from Questions " +
        "WHERE QID NOT IN " +
        "(Select TOP " + PreviouspageLimit + " QID from Questions ORDER BY QID DESC) ", con); // +
    //"order by MedicalClgID", con);
}
```

with this:

```
int intFirstRowNumber = (page - 1) * PageSize;

cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(
    "WITH AllRows AS (" +
    "SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY QID, DESC) AS RowNumber, * " +
    "FROM Questions AS Q) " +
    "SELECT QID, Question, Opt1, Opt2, Opt3, Opt4, AnsOp, Marks " +
    "FROM AllRows " +
    "WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN " + intFirstRowNumber + " AND " + (intFirstRowNumber + PageSize) +
    " ORDER BY QID, DESC", con);
```

Comment: getting this error `Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.`at this line ` this.adp1.Fill(dt);` when using second option

Comment: These codes for use *in the **Microsoft SQL SERVER** not the **Microsoft Office Access**.* *You're not referred to your Target Database in your question.* So, I added codes for the *Microsoft SQL Server*.
*The Microsoft Office Access don't support this:*
`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY QID, DESC)`

Comment: yes ,I have edited Question and added Database information in Question