# Read excel file data in batches

Tags: c#

I have an excel file that contains about 1.5 million records. My intention is to read first 100 000 records from the excel file into my datatable (here c# datatable i.e dt) do some processing on these records, then read the next 100000 records and so on until I have fetched all the records in excel file.(each time only 100000 rows)

Currently I am fetching all records using below code

```
     public bool ReadDataFile(string filePath)
    {
        string strConnString = null;
        string sheetName = null;
        string ErrSheetName = null;

        DataSet dsEx = new DataSet();


        strConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConnString);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            DataTable DtSheetName = new DataTable();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DtSheetName = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

            for (int i = 0; i <= DtSheetName.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                sheetName = DtSheetName.Rows[i]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                if (sheetName.Length >= 4)
                {

                    conn.Close();

                    conn.Open();

                    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]", conn))
                    {

                        using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                        {
                            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                            try
                            {

                                da.Fill(dt);
                                dt.TableName = sheetName.Replace("$", "");

                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                ErrSheetName = ErrSheetName + "," + sheetName.Replace("$", "");
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ReadExcel()");
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrSheetName))
            {
                 MessageBox.Show("Error in Data Of these files [" + ErrSheetName + "] Some Data may be lost !", "ReadExcel()");
            }

            conn.Close();
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do clarify what the question is exactly.

Comment: I want to fetch only 100000 records at a time from excel file in my app

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying Last 10 rows for first page than next last 10 rows for next page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18610586/displaying-last-10-rows-for-first-page-than-next-last-10-rows-for-next-page)