# How to show Left join query on datagridview on c#

Tags: c#, winforms, oledb

Thank you for all the help I've had on this website, today I would like your help. I have this issue, I want to show a left join query on a datagridview after pressing a button, the data I'm fetching is from an excel book, it's the only way I'm provided with data, in this excel sheets is contain all the data I'm working with. I will share my code, **the issue is**:

***After I click the button the datagridview updates with no data and it turns gray. thanks for you help***

The purpose of this app is to compare data between sheets, I load the tables to a combobox of sheet1, then load the attributes in another combobox of sheet1, and the same procedure with sheet2, This data to be dinamic since it will compare serveral excel sheets with different names and data types

[code from query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rv98.png)

```
    private void cargardatos(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        try
        {
           
            OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            DataSet ods = new DataSet();
            string consulta;
            //  OleDbConnection cadena;

              OleDbcon.ConnectionString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + openFileDialog.FileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");

              consulta = Convert.ToString(("Select * from [" + cmbhoja.Text + $"] as [A] LEFT JOIN [" + cmbhoja2.Text + $"] as [B] ON [A].[" + cmbcolumna.Text + $"] = [B].[" + cmbcolumna2.Text + $"]".ToString(), OleDbcon));
               
                oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(consulta, OleDbcon);

              ods.Tables.Add(cmbhoja.Text);
     
            dgv.DataSource = dt;
            this.dtvgreporte.DataSource = dgv;
            MessageBox.Show("Cruce con Exito");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code, rather than showing it as an image

Comment: Use `OleDbDataAdapter.Fill(table)` and then assign data source `dgv.DataSource = dt;`. Also `ods` not needed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30213701/read-excel-file-data-in-batches

Comment: Thanks for the assistance,, sorry for the late response, i have 2 questions                      
1. do I insert OleDbDataAdapter.Fill(table) above the dgv,datasource=dt ?                               2. i have loaded the tables on the combobox(cmbhoja) do I replace table with cmbhoja?